# flex in css3 didn't work in safari mobile

Tags: css, flexbox, mobile-safari

white line shows when use safari browse this page:

[image]

When use safari browse this page, the white line shows, and i try to use safari's flex like this to fix this but failed.

```
display:-webkit-box;
display:-webkit-flex;
display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
```

the lightland.design is fully written with css and html, hope someone can save me out of this probelm. thankyou in advanced

Comment: guys , you inspect my code in website: lightland.design

Comment: really hope someone could help me to remove the white line in displaying pics, thank u in advance.

Comment: possible help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35137085/3597276